# Change main image src attribute according thumb image click

Tags: jquery

i need to change main image src attribute according thumb image click.
But i getting only first thumb image src, not getting other thumb image src why this ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#simg").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('src'));
});  
});

<img src="main.jpg"  />

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="paddingTop">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top"><img src="1.jpg" border="0" id="simg" /></td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><img src="2.jpg" border="0" id="simg" /></td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><img src="3.jpg" border="0" id="simg" /></td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><img src="4.jpg" border="0" id="simg" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have multiple elements with the same `id`. Ids must be unique in HTML. Use a class instead:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="paddingTop">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><img src="1.jpg" border="0" class="simg" /></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><img src="2.jpg" border="0" class="simg" /></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><img src="3.jpg" border="0" class="simg" /></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><img src="4.jpg" border="0" class="simg" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".simg").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('src'));
    });  
});
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RyTwZ/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `id`, you can (SHOULD) use `class` to select multiple elements.Then use `.each` method to retrieve all elements.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you html is not valid as long as you are reusing ids. The difference between $("#simg") or $(".simg"), is that the # is returning a **single element**, but the . returns a set of elements with the same class.